# How make Transparent Background in Swiffy v7.3.0?

Tags: google-swiffy

Now in new versión of Swiffy v7.3.0 anyone knows how to make Transparent Background???

Before in previuos version this works:
#swiffycontainer div {background-color: transparent !important;}

Answer (score 0):

stage.setBackground(null);

add it before stage.start()

Comment: Yessss! Thank you Robert!